# Store and retrieve issue in Bitmap in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bitmap

I am storing bitmap in SQLite and retrieving , but images are not displaying original size . first image is displaying as `big white Dot(.)` and second image has not original size.

Here is my code to store in database:

```
public long insertProductCategoryData(String tid, String categoryName,
        Bitmap categoryImageBitmap) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    categoryImageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100,
            byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    Integer tidInteger = Integer.valueOf(tid);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHandler.TID, tidInteger);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_IMAGE, byteArray);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME, categoryName);
    long id = sqliteDB.insert(DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_TABLE, null,
            contentValues);
    return id;
}
```

Code to retrieve from the database :

```
public List<ProductCategoryBean> getProductCategoryData() {
    List<ProductCategoryBean> productCategoryBean = new ArrayList<ProductCategoryBean>();
    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = { DatabaseHandler._TID,
            DatabaseHandler.TID,
            DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME,
            DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_IMAGE };
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDB.query(DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_TABLE,
            columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            ProductCategoryBean prodCatDB = new ProductCategoryBean();
            prodCatDB.set_tid(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler._TID)));
            prodCatDB.setTid(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.TID))));
            prodCatDB.setProductCategoryName(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_NAME)));
            prodCatDB.setProductCategoryImage(cursor.getBlob(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.PRODUCT_CATEGORY_IMAGE)));
            productCategoryBean.add(prodCatDB);
        }
    } 
    dbHandler.close();
    return productCategoryBean;
}


List<ProductCategoryBean> selectQueryData = sandiskDatabaseHandler
            .getProductCategoryData();
        dbtids = new String[selectQueryData.size()];
        dblistProCategory = new String[selectQueryData.size()];
        dbimgBitmapUrls = new HashMap<Integer, Bitmap>();
        listOfProductsCategory.setNumColumns(dbtids.length);
    for (ProductCategoryBean data : selectQueryData) {
        dbtids[data.get_tid()-1] = data.getTid();
        dblistProCategory[data.get_tid()-1] = data.getProductCategoryName();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data.getProductCategoryImage() ,0, data.getProductCategoryImage() .length);
        dbimgBitmapUrls.put(data.get_tid(), bitmap);
    }
```

#### Store in cacheDir:

```
public void saveInternalCache(File folderDir, String fname, Bitmap bitmap) {

    File file = new File(folderDir, fname);

    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    if ((folderDir.mkdirs() || folderDir.isDirectory())) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("Stored");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is where i am invoking the method:

```
     File folderDir= new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(),"myimages/images");
                                                 storeImagesIndevices.saveInternalCache(folderDir,filename,imgBitmapUrls.get(‌​i));
```

Comment: store the path of images in sqlite.

Comment: @Raghunandan u meant stores the image in device and fetch from the there??

Comment: images can be stored anywhere. but store the path of the images in database. retrieve it when you want it

Comment: In sqlite is not possible to store the image in original size?? @Raghunandan

Comment: its a bad idea coz images occupies more space.

Comment: @Raghunandan in my case no of images are only 1o - 15 and size is also not that much big.

Comment: It is not recommended to store images in database. Store path to it, instead. @Raghunandan is right.

Comment: @Raghunandan this is my code to store the bitmap in Sd card what i am missing here??

public void saveInternalCache(File folderDir, String fname, Bitmap bitmap) {

  File file = new File(folderDir, fname);

  if (file.exists()) {
   file.delete();
  }
  if ((folderDir.mkdirs() || folderDir.isDirectory())) {
   try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    System.out.println("Stored");

   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: its not getting saved let me put my code above.

Comment: @Raghunandan check updated last paragraph

Comment: specify the problem you are facing

Comment: I wrote the code to store the files in cache directory but "Store in cacheDir" but in my device even directory is not existing where i gave the path

Comment: File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MY Folder"); then `if(!f.exists()){ f.makdir()}`Make sure permissions added in manifest

Comment: Yes i ahve added the permission

Comment: this is where i am invoking the method:
File folderDir= new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(),"myimages/images");
    storeImagesIndevices.saveInternalCache(folderDir,filename,imgBitmapUrls.get(i));

Comment: Not storing images/binary data in a database is such a old misconception.  Back in the days of 286 and 386 this certainly caused problems. However most cell phones these days have more computing power. I store all my data in SQLite and don't have problems.

Comment: @Namphibian i am storing my data in database but images are loosing their size. Please suggest me what to do. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you blob tybe in db for image ??.i think u should once debug the length of byte array of image before adding to db and extracting it from db. i think both are of diff sizes are the cause of this prob.inn my case using contentvalues solved my problem.